# iOS app extension to modify phone keypad

Tags: ios

I want to extend the functionality of phone keyboard.

I can't find any documentation on whether iOS 8+ has an API to do this. If it's possible can someone point me to some docs?

Comment: Do you want to make an app with a custom phone keypad UI, or you do want to override the default keypad UI on the phone app?

Comment: @nathan the latter

Answer (score 1):

The link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html says

> Your custom keyboard is also ineligible to type into so-called phone pad objects, such as the phone number fields in Contacts. These input objects are exclusively for strings built from a small set of alphanumeric characters specified by telecommunications carriers and are identified by having one or another of the following two keyboard type traits:

```
UIKeyboardTypePhonePad

UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad
```

> When a user taps in a phone pad object, the system temporarily replaces your keyboard with the appropriate, standard system keyboard. When the user then taps in a different input object that requests a standard keyboard via its type trait, your keyboard automatically resumes.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, and should be marked as such by the OP

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API to extend the functionality of the iOS phone keypad system-wide.

It is possible to create a system-wide custom keyboard ([documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html)), as well as call a phone number from an app, but not to override the system phone UI.